# Error in SSR CKIN command?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, check-in

Recently flew with UIA on a two-leg itinerary and asked them via Facebook to insert an SSR CKIN note for the first leg about me being "Docs OK" at the transit airport.

They put in the following:

> 13 SSR DOCS PS HK1 I/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY95/M/02FEB23/DEVECSERI/ANDRE
>
> 14 SSR DOCS PS HK1 I/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY95/M/02FEB23/DEVECSERI/ANDRE/S2
>
> 15 SSR DOCS PS HK1 I/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY95/M/02FEB23/DEVECSERI/ANDRE/S3
>
> 16 SSR CKIN PS HK1 PAX IN TRANSIT TO ARN WITH SWE ID CARD OK TO BOARD

However, at bag drop at BGY (manned by BGY International Services) they only saw "SSR CKIN" and not the text after that. As I had predicted, three of the present staff members (including the manager) were unable to understand the (in my opinion) clear TIMATIC information saying I can connect in Kyiv passport-free, and it was only thanks to one junior staff member, who did understand things correctly, that I was allowed to proceed.

So what I wonder is: did UIA make a computing error in row 16?
(someone told me that there should "likely" have been a / between HK1 and PAX, but they weren't too sure)

For comparison, when I flew with Belavia the format was slightly different. Given how smoothly check-in went, I *think* the bag drop staff (DNATA at GVA) saw the whole information.

> 1.SSR DOCS B2 HK1 GVAMSQ0872S26OCT/I/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY1995/M/02FEB2023/DEVECSERI/ANDRE
>
> 2.SSR DOCS B2 HK1 MSQTBS0735S26OCT/I/SWE/*****125/SWE/04MAY1995/M/02FEB2023/DEVECSERI/ANDRE
>
> 5.SSR CKIN B2 872S26OCT/PAX IN TRANSIT TO TBS WITH SWE NIDC OK TO BOARD NN1

SO it seems different airlines have slightly different formats. Again, though, can you identify any computing error in the UIA data?

Or was it the BGY computers that were faulty?

Comment: Now that’s a travel question way above the level of ordinary travellers like me. +1

Comment: Are you _sure_ you wanted to posted your full name online?

Comment: Just curious - how were you able to access the SSR information?

Comment: @JonathanReez By asking the Menzies service desk at ARN for a printout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking flight software you have to know Amadeus has a monopoly. Amadeus has [an extensive guide](https://servicehub.amadeus.com/c/portal/view-solution/968144/en_US/how-to-add-ssr-elements-to-a-pnr) on how to add SSR (Special Service Request) rows. Amadeus also provides [a list of defined SSR codes](http://api.dev.amadeus.net/api/Development/common/codelist/PNR_SSR.htm).

- Using the *SSR Code List* we can see that **CKIN** is used for "**Information for airport personnel**".
- **B2** and **PS** are the **airline codes**.
- **HK1** is **confirmed**

However there seems to be some error definining the rest of the text as "free text" (any length text). I think the person in the first sample just made something up, maybe from memory and Amadeus didn't verify the syntax correctly. The displaying application then had trouble displaying it, but if one would view the "raw data" then one could probably still see the entire text. HK1 shouldn't be on that line for example.

Comment: Amadeus has monopoly? What about Sabre and Travelport?